# Android Marketplace Error: "The server could not process your apk. Try again."

Tags: android, marketplace

I have an updated apk - tested successfully on various devices and simulator instances - with the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.myCompany.appName"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.0.1">      
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="5" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/icon_name" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name=".myActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I post to Android Marketplace as an upgrade to my existing 1.0 app, I get the aforementioned ambiguous message:

> "The server could not process your
>   apk. Try again."

I've searched elsewhere for this message in hopes of finding out what might be happening, to no avail. (A popular suggestion is to move the **uses-sdk** element to the top of the manifest, but as you can see it's *already* at the top.)

Clues welcome/appreciated.

**Update:** I just tried to upload the same file again. Now I get a new message:

> The new apk's versionCode (2) in
>   AndroidManifest.xml must be higher
>   than the old apk's versionCode (2).
>   The server could not process your apk.
>   Try again.

Soooo Marketplace *did* get my upgraded apk after all? (The very first accepted apk's versionCode was 1, so this update was of course bumped to 2.) Confused …

Bumping it up to 3 and trying again. Surprise surprise, I get the original "could not process" error all over again. Going in circles. Hmm ... :(

**Nuther Update:** If I exit and re-enter the Marketplace page, now it shows that the app has been uploaded! Except there's no app icon. Curiouser and curiouser ... and this is all happening with a cache-cleared (standards-friendly) browser to boot.

So - do I trust the upload? Or start over ... with versionCode="4"? All I want is to get a solid "Upload successful, here's the icon, ready to publish" type of response.

Comment: What is the name of your app APK as you are trying to deploy it now? What was it originally?

Comment: Same APK filename, let's call it "MyApp.apk" for the sake of argument.

If the _filename_ needs to be different, I'd expect Marketplace to warn me of that at upload-time. Happy to change it if that's what is required.

Comment: See 'Nuther Update' ... looks like the filename didn't matter. But now I'm not sure I want to trust what Marketplace has just yet either.

Comment: Not sure if this is relavent, but I had issues installing updates to several apps today on Marketplace -- they may have been having system issues.

Comment: Thanks Nate! Good to know I'm not alone. I do hope all goes well with your updates.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. I tried to upload my file several times to the market, but each time "server could not process your apk". Today I tried it again and I succeeded the first time. I made no changes to my APK and didn't remove any old ones on the market. I guess the Google server sometimes just has some problems.

Answer (score 4):

Run this tool, you can find this tool in SDK Platform Tools

`aapt dump badging <path_to_exported_.apk>`

and fix the errors. I receive this from google support.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case the reason was empty configuration tag in the manifest: 
`<uses-configuration></uses-configuration>`

Comment: Yipe. So this is sounding more and more like the error simply needs to be more descriptive ... and accompanied by a suitable remedy.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I removed the upgrade ... which ended up removing the upgrade from the queue *and* unpublishing v1.0. I quickly republished v1.0 (which was still present in the Marketplace), then posted the upgrade again.

This time it worked. No need to bump versionCode up to 4. Icon was visible too. Didn't do anything differently.

Update published. Yaaaaay!

File this under *unsolved mysteries* for now. Leaving this here in case others run in to the same problem.

**Update:** See Nate Bross's comment to the original question. Possibly some Marketplace server hiccups. Nothing official from Google yet, but it looks like I'm not the only one who ran into upgrade issues today.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. Deactivating the original APK and then uploading the update helped.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the Market is usually experiencing problems.  Visit the Known Issues page for Market Developers:

https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the Chrome Browser for Linux. After uploading with Firefox everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem that is, "**The server could not process your apk. Try again**" when i tried to upload .apk file in Google Play by last week (from India).
 After a long struggle **I successfully uploaded my .apk** when i did my upload from one of my friend's machine, (who is residing at US) through remote desktop.I think that the cause would be the location where you do your upload, that is, your nearest Google Server may not have enough space or in some server problem or in some server environmental limitations. **Hope it will help you guys...**

Answer (score 0):

i have problems too with the publisher page

...The server could not process your apk file ...

In the app overview it says (in red) that there is a draft of the new version but in "APK-Files" tab the new version does not show up.

From time to time the app does not show up in the app overview at all.

Update: the problems i experienced where solved the next day.

Comment: At the moment, everyone is experiencing this. Problem is at Google.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this exact issue. I was using the old style google developer web interface. Then I decided to click "**try the new design**" to switch to the newer one. Then when I attempted an apk upload, it failed, but at least this time I got a detailed error report.