# Android - "The server could not process your apk. Try again.." error when uploading on market

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

So this is my Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.02">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".XXXXXXXXXActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Each time I upload to the android market, I get the error:
The server could not process your apk. Try again..

I previously uploaded a few APKs, but now I decided to downgrade my app, because it works on 2.1, previously it was on minimum 2.3. And since i've changed the minSdkVersion it doesn't want to upload anymore.

Comment: Have you gone thru -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274284/android-marketplace-error-the-server-could-not-process-your-apk-try-again

Comment: Yes, error does not change at all :(.
I don't want to change version sdk although

Comment: I can't upload new apk either - same error msg. Looks like problem is at Google.

Comment: See also here for more updates on situation (and some funny comments)
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2530

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Android market is down. If you look carefully, you will see that upload does not even happen. So that error message is misleading you. Lets wait till Google resolves this.

Comment: How to report this problem? Looks like they still don't know about it.

Comment: Check here for Known Issues:

https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs

Answer (score 4):

@o2genum

I reported the problem here:

https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=bugs

(under "problems with the developer console")

And sent them the URL to this report

Edit:
Just saw this in the console:

22 February 2012: Application uploading and editing issues.
We are aware of issues with uploading and editing applications in the Android Market Developer Console. We apologize for this inconvenience and are working to fix this as soon as we can.

Comment: it seemed they fixed it a few days after this post :)  But as always with the dev console, old problems sometimes find their way back.